# DKIM signature and hmailserver - Your DKIM signature is not valid

Tags: dkim

I'm trying to get DKIM working on a domain using hmailserver as the mailserver, but I keep on getting **Your DKIM signature is not valid**

This is from www.mail-tester.com

```
The DKIM signature of your message is:

v=1;
a=rsa-sha256;
d=twitterautopost.co.uk;
s=key1;
c=simple/simple;
q=dns/txt;
h=From:Subject:Date:Message-ID:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
bh=UmH1WrduLl3abcMsoAbrWmKA9BGd7W0M4NcX7EZqo/s=;
b=ibp5puhoKfSAeV4GUxCAV+YQd25s2/GiBA7k7dFmSSIjpcwIyau54545SdTRmF8yLDCrVCkll+fa2VERESLpNWDnYyQXrW+BjhSTRcDOnYYKTCghkbNc4FaspEdRvuMzzL1OeQ7LFsrp9HJ6N0NheRIyDQAG4hFM=

Your public key is:

"k=rsa\\;
p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4G6WPaESxPzkXT1jsC+ivorJij0gXi39XlBFJfB1/M+quGClJPNquvJAeEWZ7SOQI7pRPcvnwySapJMfjIlH7n23F4eDwkJO8lEvC5HhTM13Ecz5QVe+/jM8jUgGjuF57NsCmPXMXw6TAKcFUyNcK6plnfsRyzgBbGLZr2ishWZQIDAQAB"
Key length: 1024bits

Your DKIM signature is not valid
```

(I removed some characters from the keys)

I have made a TXT entry into the domains DNS as follows :

```
key1._domainkey.twitterautopost.co.uk = k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDM6WPaESxPzkXT1jsC+ivorJij0gXi39XlBFJfB1/M+quGClJPNquvJAeEWZ7SOQI7pRPcv3F4eDwkJO8lEvC5HhTM13Ecz5QVe+/jM8jUgGjuF57NsCmPXMXw6TAKcFUyNcK6plnfsRyzgBbGLZr2ishWZQIDAQAB
```

Not sure what to try now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your answer, I'm facing same error

Answer (score 0):

The key doesn't seem to be RSA public key.

I see the latest record that exists on key1._domainkey.twitterautopost.co.uk is validated correctly.